# folder.getOwner does not return the correct value / Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

my google script code isn't returning the name of the creator for "folder.getOwner" I am getting this:

function () { [native code] }

The exact same is happening for "folder.getDescription"

The code is supposed to get the data from a folder path and insert the data in a google sheet such as the person who created it, description, date, etc.
This is the output I am getting on google sheet:
02 Banking Insurance -> Fintech -> Customer01 -> function () { [native code] } -> function () { [native code] } -> function () { [native code] } -> 11/7/2020 2:24:12

I do not know why, can someone help?

```
function addRowToSheetForFolder(folder) {
  var FolderBanking = DriveApp.getFolderById("FolderID");
  data = [
             
             FolderBanking, //Parent folder
             folder.getName(),
             folder.getName().toString(),
             folder.getDateCreated,
             folder.getDescription,
             folder.getOwner,
             //editors.toString(), // find out how to add the editor
             //viewers.toString(),
             folder.getDateCreated(),
            // folder.getSize(),
             folder.getUrl(),
             "https://docs.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=" + folder.getId(),
             folder.getDescription(),
             folder.getMimeType,
         ];
  Logger.log("Writing row to sheet");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow(data);
```

EDIT: It is not possible to retrieve the creator from a folder in the shared drive it only works on MyDrive -> getOwner() will always retrieve null

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you need to gather with "folder.getMimeType". This is because the getMimeType() method is only applicable to a FILE and not to a FOLDER as per (Drive's "Class File" methods article) at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getmimetype. And please share the complete script (we don't want to assume the origin of the "folder" on addRowToSheetForFolder(folder)) so we can replicate the issue properly. Lastly, you'll need to add () (open & close parenthesis) at the end of the getOwner & getDescription on your script because these are methods too.

Comment: rest of the code: 
`function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var topFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("13C4cnxnzNP_HMItTiS5PpuyQgWovUuF_");
  var topPath = "/";
  sheet.appendRow(["Industry", "Client", "Projectname", "Folder ID"])

  iterateSubFolders(topFolder, topPath)
}

function iterateSubFolders(callingFolder, callingPath, sheet) {

  var callingFolderName = callingFolder.getName();
  var callingFolderFullPath = callingPath + callingFolderName + "/";
  Logger.log(callingFolderFullPath);
     
  addRowToSheetForFolder(callingFolder)`

Comment: I do not know how to post it in a cleaner way sorry! Due to the character restriction i wasnt able to post the entire code so the function addRowToSheetForFolder is above in the original question